# Vuejs and Nodejs deploying to heroku: $ npm run dev works but not $ node server.js

Tags: node.js, heroku, vue.js, vue-cli, snipcart

I made a website with Vue.js and included Snipcart API for a buy button. I've been trying to deploy it to heroku for 2 days now.

When I enter `$ npm run dev` it works fine and will display my web app. But for some reason if I do `$ node server.js` it shows the default Vue welcome page for its webpack ("Welcome to Your Vue App").

I've tried entering `"start":"npm run dev"` in my package.json but that just results in a forever loading web page. If I enter `"start":"node server.js"` It results in the same thing as the previous paragraph, it just shows the default Vue welcome page.

I found someone with basically the same issue ([How to set up vue(2)-cli app to run with nodejs server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50659418/how-to-set-up-vue2-cli-app-to-run-with-nodejs-server)) and even tried the same tutorial post but I don't know what that comment/answer is talking about. I am also unsure of how to deploy a static website with a Snipcart API (as a previous user mentioned to me in a previous post).

I am really at a loss as to what to do. Thanks for your time.

Edit: Here is the repo for my app: https://github.com/Taikon/MaroonRiver0

Comment: Without more information, it seems like `npm run dev` is running some sort of live server without actually building anything. and `npm start` serves the built assets (which are still the defaults because you didn't build anything).

Comment: Apologies, I should have included the files. I added the repo with all my files to my main post. Here it is again: https://github.com/Taikon/MaroonRiver0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly what I suspected in the comment: You are not building your assets.

Run

```
npm run build
node server.js
```

And it should work as expected.

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much! It worked! So now I know I have to run build everytime I make a change